Temperature Sensor Auto
I'm trying to make a temperature sensor for a Golf MK2, with an LM3914N to light an LED bar with 10 LEDs and in the signal I'm using a voltage divider for R2 to be the temperature sensor that operates from 2000 ohm (cold) to 100 ohm (warm). So far my only problem is inverting the signal to access the LEDs when the resistance is lower.
I made an oil pressure sensor that operates from 0.6 to 600 ohms and it went well, after adjusting the Rh and the signal started working properly.
Can anyone help me or tell me what I can do to solve my problem with voltage inversion?
(I've already used an NPN to invert but it's a switch that doesn't work for variable voltages and I've also tried using the lm358N but I couldn't invert the signal.)

Is the temperature sensor connected to GND on one side?

yes, GND connected to engine

I assume, you want to use the LM3914 configured as shown in figure 1 of the datasheet. Then REF_OUT provides 5.0 V and this is the signal input range.
This circuit uses the stable 5 V reference voltage to feed the sensor path R2/R1 and the offset voltage divider R5/R6.
To keep the currents low, the voltage division factor is around 10:1, which will not have a large impact on the LED current setup of the LM3914.
The voltage gain of the inverter is defined by R4/R3.
You may want to connect a load resistor of e.g. 10 kΩ at the output of the LM358 to help reaching 0 V.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The relation between sensor resistance and output voltage looks like this:

